# How to create following table using MDX Scripting in Sql Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, mdx

I have the following table ,

- Database Table:

  ```
  BatchID    BatchName      Chemical      Value
  ----------------------------------------------
  BI-1          BN-1       CH-1             1

  BI-2          BN-2       CH-2             2
  ----------------------------------------------
  ```

I need to display the following table.

```
                 BI-1          BI-2
                 BN-1          BN-2
-----------------------------------------
CH-1             1            null
------------------------------------------
CH-2             null          2
------------------------------------------
```

Here BI-1,BN-1 are two rows in a single columns i need to display chemical value as row of that.Could Please help me to solve this problem.

I tried it in Pivot table but i unable to get this.
So is there any chance in Reporting Server MDX.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a cube with Analysis Services (MDX only works against multidimensional data sources)

Then, assuming you have a cube "MYCUBE" with "Batch" and "Chemical" dimensions and a "Value" measure, the query would be something like this (of course, you could select just the members you need instead of all the members in the dimensions):

```
SELECT 
    {[Batch].members * [Measures].[Value]} on columns,
    {[Chemical].members} on rows
FROM [MYCUBE]
```

Comment: I am new to this MDX and cube how to create a cube for it

Comment: That's obviously outside the scope of a StackOverflow question. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc510300.aspx, and get yourself one of the books recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101242/nice-book-on-sql-server-analysis-services